# Calling action from async action in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my file for action creators in my react app.
Inside my  async **getHomePage** action I am trying to call setLoading() action which is not getting called. When I comment my code below in my try block and only keep setLoading() then it works and I can see setLoading called in redux dev tools. But when I keep my whole code it gives me **SET_HOME** and not **SET_LOADING**.
Is there something I am doing wrong by calling another action from async action.

```
import axios from '../axios/default.instance';
import {
    SET_LOADING, 
    SET_HOME
} from './types';

export const getHomePage = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
       setLoading();
       const result = await axios.get("/home");
       dispatch({
           type:SET_HOME,
           payload: result.data
       });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

export const setLoading = () => {
    return {
        type: SET_LOADING
    }
}
```

Comment: `dispatch(setLoading())`

Comment: Thanks, It works. You can put it as answer, I can upvote It